# Ajax to ActionResult, getting Model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have an action (Index) that return a View with a concrete model.

Inside that view (Is a calendar) I have two buttons to change months.

When I click one of those I call back Index action to that will return the same view with a modified model.

```
$("#right").live("click", function () {
    $.post($(this).attr("href"), function (response) {
        $("#wrapper").replaceWith($(response).filter("div#wrapper"));
    });
    return false;
});
```

So, I click #right and it call /Home/Index and Index return something like:

```
return View(new DateViewModel(dt, _bDays.GetDaysFromMonth(dt)));
```

So as you see, I replace div#wrapper with the new one. Perfect but...

Is there a way to get the model of the response? I mean, that action return a view with a model and apart from getting the concrete div I want the model.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you would need the model in the AJAX callback, and thus there is probably a better solution than the one I am about to propose. So you could have your controller action [render the partial view into a string](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/) and then return a JSON object containing both the HTML and the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    MyViewModel model = new DateViewModel(dt, _bDays.GetDaysFromMonth(dt));
    string html = RenderPartialToString("partialName", model);
    return Json(new { Model = model, Html = html });
}
```

and in your AJAX callback:

```
$.post($(this).attr("href"), function (response) {
    var model = response.Model;
    var html = response.Html;
    $("#wrapper").replaceWith($(html).filter("div#wrapper"));
});
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks, my app is a little more faster and I learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to call a separate controller action and return a `JsonResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return Json(new DateViewModel(dt, _bDays.GetDaysFromMonth(dt)));
}
```

This action will return a JSON representation of your ViewModel that you can reference in your AJAX response.

Comment: Yeah, I know that way but it's an extra ajax call, one for changing month and one to get the days. I prefer 1 if possible. Thanks anyway.